# Python string interpolation: only show necessary decimal places

Tags: python, string, formatting

If I have for example x = 40 I want the following result:

```
40"
```

For x = 2.5 the result should be like...

```
2.5"
```

So I basically want to format to at most one decimal place. I currently use this:

```
"{0:0.1f}\"".format(x, 1)
```

But this displays always exactly one decimal place, which is not really what I want...

Comment: Do you want to round or truncate the trailing digits?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is something like

```
"{0}\"".format(str(round(x, 1) if x % 1 else int(x)))
```

which will display `x` as an integer if there's no fractional part. There's quite possibly a better way to go about this.

Comment: No problem :) Glad that helps. Although curious to see if anyone else has a cleaner way to go about this.

Comment: What is the 2nd arg to `format(...)` for? (here: 1)

Comment: @lajarre Good question. No idea why I put that there. Removed.

Comment: amount = (str(round(amount, 2) if amount % 1 else int(amount)))

Answer (score 5):

This is reusable, can be used on `str`, `float`, or `int`, and will convert `''` to `0`:

```
def minimalNumber(x):
    if type(x) is str:
        if x == '':
            x = 0
    f = float(x)
    if f.is_integer():
        return int(f)
    else:
        return f
```

Use with:

```
print "{}\"".format(minimalNumber(x))
```

Example:

```
x = 2.2
print "{}\"".format(minimalNumber(x))
x = 2.0
print "{}\"".format(minimalNumber(x))
```

Which outputs:

```
2.2"
2"
```

Comment: You might want to use `float(x).is_integer()` to allow for the use of integers. (`is_integer` is not defined for integers)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not necessarily completely clean solution, but I think at least a little bit more explicit:

```
"{1:0.{0}f}\"".format(int(not float(x).is_integer()), x)
```

which may be replaced with more cryptic (based on Michael Mior rounding idea):

```
"{1:0.{0}f}\"".format(int(x % 1 > 0), x)
```

if you prefer shorter expressions (less pythonic though).

Comment: For once I see the real usefulness of `format`. And the 2nd version is superior to me (cleaner)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 2.50
b = 42.0
c = 900.0
print("{0:.1f}".format(a).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))
print("{0:.1f}".format(b).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))
print("{0:.1f}".format(c).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))
```

Output:

```
2.5
42
900
```

Comment: @dom0 @hitzg is right, using rstrip('0.') would strip `900.0` down to `9`, in opposite to `rstrip('0').rstrip('.')`, which correctly results in `900`. Notice that `"{0:.1f}".format(...)` will always have atleast one decimal place, such that `900` will be formated to `900.0`, which will be stripped down to `900` again.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford changing your result type, you can use a simple check:

```
if float(x) == int(x):
    print(int(x))
else:
    print(x)
```

Not fancy, but intuitive.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This certainly works for the case where showing no decimal points is desirable, but it doesn't quite answer the user's question, since they also want it to handle floats like 2.5.

Comment: Thanks for both the welcome and the pointing the problem, @s3cur3