# Always int divide int = float in Python

Tags: python, integer

My problem is when I divide a number like: 10 / 2 → integer / integer.

The result is 5.0 and it is float, but it shouldn't be float. The problem is Python adds 0.0 to every number accept to divide with the second number.

So I want 10/2 be integer.

I tried

```
x = 10
y = x/2
type(y) == int
```

It prints false. I want type(y) print the true result although x was a prime or odd number.

Comment: Why do you _need_ the result to be an int?

Answer (score 5):

`/` gives a floating point result. If you want an integer result, use `//`.

The reason it works like this is that if you have something like

```
function1() / function2()
```

it is possible to tell the type of the result even if you don't know the types returned by the individual functions.

**Edit 1**

Note that it has not always been this way. This is a "new" Python 3 behaviour, also available (but not active by default) for Python 2.2 onwards - see [PEP 238](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/). Thanks to @Steve314 for pointing this out.

**Edit 2**

However, it seems that what you are really trying to do is tell if one number goes exactly into another. For this you should use `%` (remainder)

```
print(15 % 5 == 0) 
print(16 % 3 == 0)
```

This prints

```
True
False
```

**Edit 3**

If you want the type of the result to depend on whether the division goes exactly, you would need to do

```
a // b if a % b == 0 else a / b
```

Comment: it tried to divide for exp : x=  10 / 5 
type(x) == int and it's print false it should be int

Comment: I tried 
x = 10
y= x/2 
type(y)== int it print false

Comment: @user_user Try `x = 10 y = x // 2 print(type(y) == int)`. You should get `true`.

Comment: ok when I change x to x=9  y= x//2    type(y)== int it will be true and it is false

Comment: @user_user When you do `//` the result is an int, even if the second number does not go exactly into the first. I think it works by dividing the numbers and rounding down to an integer.

Comment: the big problem is when I divide 10 / 5 it print 2.0 the .0 is the problem which it makes the result not int

Comment: but 9//2 gives 4 
It should be 4.5

Comment: but 9//2 gives 4 It should be 4.5

Comment: I want to python print the real answer without .0 if there is no need

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507554/python-string-interpolation-only-show-necessary-decimal-places) and accepted answer - I think it does what you want.

Comment: – Paul Boddington
 thank you a lot 
I saw your last edited it's what I mean
thanks

Comment: @user_user Glad I could help.